Wrong keyboard layout only in fluent program window
I have a german keyboard and Ubuntu is set up to use the german keyboard layout.
I have a weird bug and haven't been able to find anything like it online. I connect to a Linux vncserver using tigervnc to have a graphical instance, and everywhere I try, the keyboard works normally with a single exception. Writing in the File Manager and in the terminal work perfectly for example.
My problem occurrs only when I start a program called Fluent. Only inside the fluent GUI does the keyboard layout get messed up and only if fluent is started from inside the tigervnc window. Starting fluent from a ssh terminal session on the server without using any vncserver has no keyboard layout problems.
The mapping of the keyboard keys becomes:
1->9
2->0
3->-
4->=
5->(delete or backspace?)
6-> (nothing/unknown)
7->q
8->w
9->e
0->8
q->c
w->.
e->g
r->v
t->n
z->*
u->m
i->l
o->z
p->x
a->a
s->b
d->f
f->h
g->j
h->k
j->;
k->'
l->`
Has anyone seen something similar and can nudge me in the correct direction to resolve this problem? I have tried googling but have only found posts for the wrong keyboard layout in the entire OS; I haven't found any bug report of it only happening in a single program. Let me know if any extra Information is required or a command to run on the terminal to help resolve the problem.
Many thanks in advance

I was able to find similar problems here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581204/qt-xkeyboard-extension-not-present-on-the-x-server
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=814959
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3713
It seems the error is related to a Qt XKEYBOARD problem using tightvnc as a vnc server. I will try and install tigervnc as a vnc server using sudo apt-get install tigervnc-standalone-server and update

That fixed the problem

I was able to find similar problems here: unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581204/… bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=814959 github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3713 It seems the error is related to a Qt XKEYBOARD problem using tightvnc as a vnc server. I will try and install tigervnc as a vnc server using sudo apt-get install tigervnc-standalone-server and update – Pepe Juanx
May 2 at 12:30 Delete
